# How to refresh gridview to load another table having diffrent condition

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am having trouble to refresh my gridview to view another table from 2nd condition. I used databind(); But unfortunately it comes with runtime error, the reason is the other table that I was going to view in 1st condition has different fields from the first table I displayed. Below is my code, I hope you can help me..

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. DatePicker1.Text;
            DateTime dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g.  DatePicker1.Text
            MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=P@$$W0RD");
            MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from bio_db.direct_inc_dtr where Date between '" + dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dtTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ", mcon);

            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            mcon.Open();
            mda.Fill(ds, "root");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["root"];

            mcon.Close();

        }
        else if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {

            DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g. DatePicker1.Text;
            DateTime dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text); //some DateTime value, e.g.  DatePicker1.Text
            MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=P@$$W0RD");
            MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from bio_db.prob_logs_out where Date between '" + dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dtTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ", mcon);

            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            mcon.Open();
            mda.Fill(ds, "root");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["root"];

            mcon.Close();
        }
```

---

```
  (1st condition) dtfrom and dttime  1st table 
   - To filter Gridview by Date base on what date or cutoff user input.

  (2nd condition) Radiobutton   two other datatable
-  To be select by user what to view and filtered by date base on the Date inputed by users from the 1st condition.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not create two GridView, one for each and just hide/show one depending on value of your RadioButton?

Comment: Instead of custom columns in Gridview, use AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Comment: @Dr.Stitch i also think that option if i will not solved this 1 gridview. But i think i will not do that now, i already figure out the problem.

Comment: @Sami yes you are correct, i changed that AutoGenerateColumns to "True" and in addition i add the two table in my SourceData. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Glad to help ... vote up if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use    `AutoGenerateColumns = "True"` in gridview